# Escaping exclamation mark in shell (negation for if/then construct)?

Tags: bash, escape-characters

I often use this directly in a shell to test an outcome for scripting, and it works fine:

```
$ if [ -d mydirectory ] ; then echo YES ; fi
YES
```

However, if I want to use the negation using exclamation mark, it fails (*well, not really fails, but goes into multiline mode waiting for keyboard input, and I have to escape using Ctrl-C*):

```
$ if [ ! -d makehuman ] ; then echo YES ; if
> 
> ^C
$ if [ \! -d makehuman ] ; then echo YES ; if
> 
> ^C
```

How can I use the negation exclamation mark directly in a shell?

Comment: I put `$?` in my `PS1` so the prompt always shows the exit status of the last foreground command.  This makes testing conditions as easy as  running `[ -d mydir ]` and looking at my current prompt.  Another way to test with less typing and w/o using the prompt is `[ -d mydir ] && echo yes`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @jw013, wasn't aware about `$?` - cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a syntax error, the above commands should finish with `fi` not `if`

```
$ if [ ! -d mydirectoryNO ] ; then echo YES ; fi
YES
```

Anyway, I also found this nice related link: [The classic test command [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Answer (score 1):

At the Bash command line, the exclamation point can be escaped with a backslash, just like all special characters. Don't forget the correct `if` syntax, though!

```
$ if [ \! -d mydirectory ]; then echo Yay; else echo Nay; fi
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @Kerrek SB - good to keep that in mind... Cheers!